# Full screen website using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen

I am using below code for full screen website on all browser. But my code working on mozila browser only, when i browse my site on chrome browser and make it full screen, it's not previewed full screen, its showed me narrow screen.

Here is my code:

```
console.clear();
var elem = document.getElementById("fullScreen");
function requestFullScreen(elt) {
    console.log("Requesting fullscreen for", elt);
    if (elt.requestFullscreen) {
      elt.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elt.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elt.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elt.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elt.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elt.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elt.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
        console.error("Fullscreen not available");
    }
}
document.getElementById("Fullscreen").addEventListener("click", function () {
    requestFullScreen( 
        document.getElementById("FullScreen") 
    );
});
```

If you don't understand, please comment here, i will update my post with more information. thanks

Comment: please show you html code

Answer (score 0):

Chrome might not be entering full screen due to one out of various reasons such as denial of permission.

You should set up `fullscreenerror` and `fullscreenerror` events before calling `requestFullscreen`. This way you can inspect the condition and get information about why Chrome fails to enter full screen.

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenerror ", function( event) {

    console.log(event);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your inputs I have attached a code which is being tested in **Chrome & Firefox**. Kindly refer to below code for better understanding.

```js
console.clear();
var elem = document.getElementById("fullScreen");

function requestFullScreen(elt) {
  console.log("Requesting fullscreen for", elt);
  if (elt.requestFullscreen) {
    elt.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elt.msRequestFullscreen) {
    elt.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elt.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    elt.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elt.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    elt.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else {
    console.error("Fullscreen not available");
  }
}
document.getElementById("fullScreen").addEventListener("click", function() {
  requestFullScreen(elem);
});
```

```css
#fullScreen {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullScreen" title="Go Fullscreen"></div>
```

Copy the snippet in any real HTML files and try checking. Here it may not work.
**If still, you feel any doubt feel free to comment.**